# Kubernetes environment variable update policy

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-apiserver

I'm writing an application that dynamically deploys kubernetes resources. On each deploy, I set environment variables in the `Container` within the `DeploymentSpec` with the golang api (see https://godoc.org/k8s.io/api/core/v1#Container). Is there any reason why I'm not seeing changes in these variables on the pod?

For example, when I change my codebase to set `FOO: "hi"` to `FOO: "hello"`, the variable isn't updated in the application.

Based on other answers, its probably important to note that my "checking" of the environment variables is happening at docker run time. That is, for debugging, I'm running `printenv` in the `CMD` field of the kubernetes container.

A snippet of env variables being printed before `Create()` on the deployment:

```
...

v1.EnvVar{
   Name:      "FOO",
   Value:     "foo",
},
v1.EnvVar{
   Name:      "BAR",
   Value:     "arb",
},

...
```

Any leads are greatly appreciated!

Comment: do other spec fields change (ie. image) ? are your pods recreated after you deploy changes ?

Comment: What causes the updated deployment to actually be written out?  If you `kubectl get deployment -o yaml` something you generated, does its spec match what you have?  Is a failing pod preventing the deployment from proceeding?